# Adding table values to a treeview

Tags: database, vb.net, treeview

I am using Vb 2008 express edition and am very new to treeviews. i have basic knowledge of how to connect to a database. the database i am working with is a microsoft access database and has a large amount of tables with various information. two of these tables i need to put into a treeview. one has 2 columns called date and date id, the date will be the main nodes on the treeview. the other table has 8 colums, among them are the corresponding date id's from the first table, the purchase order id and the purchase order number. the child nodes will be the purchase order number.

Now i know there are a bunch of tutorials out there on treeview population through microsoft access databases but i have found none specifically with what i need, they are all just about dumping ALL the data from the database into the table. i just want specific contents of two tables. if someone could help me out with this i would be very grateful. i can give more information if needed on what i am working with or anything else.!

[This](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rSItq.png) is an example of what it needs to look like. i am upgrading this program from vb6 to vb.net which is why i already have the program.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you will have to do is loop through the first table (using sql and a datareader, for example) and then create the initial (parent) nodes.  (Note that the below is a general idea, you will have to figure out the loop and datareader parts).

```
looping structure
    TreeView1.Nodes.Add(nodeName, nodeName)
next record
```

Then, loop through the second table, adding the record to the correct node...

```
looping structure
    TreeView1.Nodes(parentNodeName).Nodes.Add(nodeName, nodeName)
next record
```

Comment: This is a good start for me but again im not that experienced with all this stuff so i still dont really know how to progress from that

Comment: Just look up DataReader.  Here is a relevant article.  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/haa3afyz(v=vs.110).aspx You would basically be modifying the SQL statement and putting the code above for the TreeView.Nodes inside of the Do WHile loop.